# Synchronize multiple data sources in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have 3 different sources for data.

1. Metadata stream
2. Record stream
3. Metadata table

For the first time I want my application to build metadata by scanning complete table and save it to Flink's ValueState. Updates on the table will be captured via metadata stream and ValueState will be updated accordingly.

From second time, I want to use the ValueState instead of reading entire table.

Here is what I am doing,

1. Read entire table and pass it as `datasource` through constructor to CustomCoFlatMap.
2. For each record received in Metadata stream, update ValueState
3. For each record received in Record stream, get metadata from ValueState and collect output.

```
DataStream<Metadata> metadataKeyedStream =
    env.addSource(metadataStream)
        .keyBy(Metadata::getId);

SingleOutputStreamOperator<Output> outputStream =
    env.addSource(recordStream)
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new RecordTimeExtractor())
        .keyBy(Record::getId)
        .connect(metadataKeyedStream)
        .flatMap(new CustomCoFlatMap(metadataTable.listAllAsMap()));

public class CustomCoFlatMap extends RichCoFlatMapFunction<Record, Metadata, Output> {

    private transient Map<String, Metadata> datasource;
    private transient ValueState<String, Metadata> metadataState;

    @Inject
    public void setDataSource(Map<String, Metadata> datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        // read ValueState
        metadataState = getRuntimeContext().getState(
            new ValueStateDescriptor<String, Metadata>("metadataState", Metadata.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap2(Metadata metadata, Collector<Output> collector) throws Exception {
        // if metadata record is removed from table, removing the same from local state
        if(metadata.getEventName().equals("REMOVE")) {
            metadataState.clear();
            return;
        }
        // update metadata in ValueState
        this.metadataState.update(metadata);
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap1(Record record, Collector<Output> collector) throws Exception {
        
        Metadata metadata = this.metadataState.value();
        // if metadata is not present in ValueState
        if(metadata == null) {
            // get metadata from datasource
            metadata = datasource.get(record.getId());
            // if metadata found in datasource, add it to ValueState
            if(metadata != null) {
                metadataState.update(metadata);
                Output output = new Output(record.getId(), metadataState.getName(), 
                    metadataState.getVersion(), metadata.getType());

                collector.collect(output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my questions,

1. I am reading from Metadata table everytime, I need to do it only once and if I restart the application, I should only read from ValueState.
2. How do I know that Metadata and Record streams are in sync, how to make sure that I am not reading Record with timestamp 12:00 and Metadata with timestamp 12:05 (I need to read Metadata at 12:00 as it might be changed by 12:05).

Comment: Hi,
Can you clarify exactly how `metadataTable` is loaded? 
Since it is available in the code that does things like `.flatMap(new CustomCoFlatMap(metadataTable.listAllAsMap()));`, it would have to contain data small enough to fit inside the node running the `main()` method, and then gets serialized to the workerNodes.
If this assumption about size is wrong, then I suggest to move it out, maybe only relying on the metadata stream. If this assumption is right, then it's small and reloading it each time would be cheap.
(Or maybe I missed your point?)

Comment: `MetadataTable` is loaded when there is any change in version of the `Record`. It is very less frequently updated table and number of records are also very less. It is cheap to reload each time, but if my application stops at 14:00, and starts at 15:30, I will process records waiting in streams in order from 14:00, if I reload from table, I get Metadata at 15:30 which I do not want.